# Twilio message sending with proxy server

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Following piece of code works without proxy

**Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(number), messagingServiceId, smsMessage).create();**

But I am unable to send the message when proxy is enabled.
Is there any specification from Twilio to send messages using proxy authentication?

Comment: Can you provide a bit of more code context please?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid I'm not a Java developer really, but I can point you in the right direction.

When you initialise `Twilio` you can also set a custom `restClient`. You can [build a new `restClient`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twilio/http/TwilioRestClient.java) and pass a custom `httpClient`. By default, this is an instance of the [`NetworkHttpClient`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/f38f9e8a4fbf64b3fe1e695c07c23e8ec8afafcb/src/main/java/com/twilio/http/NetworkHttpClient.java) but you could extend that class to include your proxy credentials.

Underneath it all is the Apache HTTP Components client. [In the docs there is an example of a client with a proxy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) which I suggest you take a look at.

Sorry I couldn't be more specific, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Now I am able to send the message with proxy enabled

Comment: Fantastic! Since this helped, do you mind marking the answer as the solution. It will help others if they have the same trouble.